# Heatmap distortion in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I managed to generate the heatmap in R using heatmap function 
   ( `heatmap(heatmap_16m, col=redgreen(75)`)
to get the following:

[image]

As you see, it has a normal distribution of red, black and green colors.

Since heatmap function cannot provide any legend, I switched to heatmap.2 function (`heatmap.2(heatmap_16m, col= redgreen(75), trace="none")`) and got the following:

[image]

Here the color distribution is skewed to mainly red.

So, my question is following: how to get the apperance (legend, row and column dendrogram order) as in second heatmap with the distribution of greens and reds as in first heatmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer accidentally while searching for something else :)
Here it goes:

```
heatmap.2(heatmap_16m, col= greenred(75), trace="none", 
      scale="row")
```

You can also scale by column, depending on the data.